# Vb.net connection using odbc

Tags: vb.net, odbc

[image]

Hi can someone help me. In very noob at vb. Im just trying to connect my ms access to vb using odbc. The connection is always not connected. Im sure that the path is right and the db name.

Comment: DO NOT POST PICTURES OF CODE!  Code is text.  Post it as text, then format it as code.

Comment: ODBC should be your last option for connecting to a database.  Use OLE DB for Access.  See www.connectionstrings.com for appropriate connection string.  Either way, do you have Microsoft Office installed on your system?  If not, you will need to install the standalone ACE database engine in order to connect to ACCDB files.

Comment: Did you bother to actually look at the exception to see what the actual reason is?  The system is trying to tell you what happened and you're just ignoring it.

Comment: @jmcihinney: do not post code as pictures and do not shout in upper case, both is rude.

Comment: ```C\Users\...``` does not seem very correct to me, I guess that should be ```C:\Users\...``` instead.